# Pass Vec as Iterator to function

Tags: rust

What I want to do:

- I have a struct that includes a `Vec` of another struct.
- I will update this `Vec` from time to time.
- I want to pass this `Vec` as a `Iterator` to another function.

Here follows a short code snippet of how I want to do things but I just can't get it to compile whatever I do:

```
struct Main {
    data: Vec<OtherStruct>
}

callFunctionHere(self.data.iter());

pub fn callFunctionHere<I>(data: I)
where
     I: Iterator<Item = OtherStruct>,
{
   // for i in data...
}
```

Could I pass the data as a new copied object of some sort?

Answer (score 4):

You need a trait bound of `Iterator<Item = &OtherStruct>`, since `Vec<T>::iter` returns an iterator over *references* to `T`. An iterator producing `T` values would have to move them out of the vector, which is safe only if the vector itself is consumed, and is what `Vec<T>::into_iter()` does.

Note that you'll need to also specify a lifetime of the reference, tied to lifetime of the data:

```
fn some_function<'a, I>(data: I)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a Other> + 'a,
{
    for el in data {
        println!("{:?}", el)
    }
}
```

Complete example [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1bf61110c657a18c787d83c616e872e7).

Finally, it's worth pointing out that in general it is preferred to request the [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) bound instead of `Iterator`. Since `Iterator` implements `IntoIterator`, such function would keep accepting iterators, but would also accept objects that can be converted into iterators. In this case it would accept `&s.data` in addition to `s.data.iter()`.

Comment: Then i get "explicit lifetime name needed here" where i Put the &

Comment: @liljan Yes, the compiler can't infer the lifetime of the reference, so you need to specify it explicitly. I've now amended the answer to show an example.

Comment: You should almost always bound argument types on `IntoIterator` instead of `Iterator`, because it is more general; e.g., in this case you could also pass `some_function(&s.data)` without having to call `iter()`.

Comment: @trentcl Good pooint, thanks. I've now amended the answer, leaving the function as-is for simplicity, but adding a paragraph that advertises the advantages of `IntoIterator`.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by:

```
callFunctionHere(data.iter().map(|i| OtherStruct{
    d: i.d
})
´´´
```

Comment: This is probably not what you want. If you really want to make a copy of the struct, `data.iter().cloned()` will do the job as long as `OtherStruct` implements `Clone`. But if `callFunctionHere` doesn't need to consume the `OtherStruct`s, you should make it accept references instead and follow user4815162342's answer.